# Sharepoint 2013 App URL change

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin

When I deploy a Sharepoint App to Publishing site, I get some random URL like this

```
http://apps-a24b65bc61856d.domain.com.
```

How can give a fixed URL for this app?

And also Sharepoint App doesn't show logged in username on the right top corner.

[image]

What we need to do to display the username?

Comment: Why do you need to update the URL? To get control over the URL you would have to create a Provider Hosted add-in instead, hosting the logic in your own web app

Comment: But I'm using Sharepoint hosted app. Is there any way to change the URL for that?

Comment: No there is not, and again, why do you need that to happen?

Comment: I was thinking that, If I give fixed URL I can share the URL with users so that it will be easy to access since the current URL is not readable.

Comment: and do you have any idea on the second part of my question? 'Sharepoint App doesn't show logged in username on the right top corner'